# Use the Residue theorem and its application to compute the integral

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4-4x^2+5} dx. $$

I am not sure how to approach this question. Can anyone use the complex variable theory to help me solving the problem please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know what the residue theorem implies? For example, can you think of a way to use the solutions to $x^4 - 4x^2 + 5 = 0$?

Comment: @T.Bongers: I was trying to factor it, but I am not sure how to factor it into the expression with z and i

Answer (score 2):

HINT:  The roots of $x^4 - 4x^2 + 5$ in the upper half-plane are $\sqrt{2 + i}$ and $- \sqrt{2 - i}$ (to factor, think about $x^4 - 4x^2 + 5$ as a quadratic in the variable $x^2$).  Then think about integrating over a semicircular contour $\gamma = [- R, R] \cup S$, where
$$ S = \{ R e^{it} : 0 \leq t \leq \pi \}. $$
Let $R \to \infty$.

Comment: Hi, how can I factor it into the expression of z and i. Thanks.

Comment: "...to factor, think about $x^4 - 4x^2 + 5$ as a quadratic in the variable $x^2$...".  Then use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^{2} \over x^{4} - 4x^{2} + 5}\,\dd x
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{x^{2}
 \over
 \bracks{x^{2} - \pars{2 - \ic}}\bracks{x^{2} - \pars{2 + \ic}}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{x^{2}
 \over
 \pars{x^{2} - \root{5}\expo{-\ic\phi}}\pars{x^{2} - \root{5}\expo{\ic\phi}}}\,\dd x
 \quad\mbox{where}\quad\phi = \arctan\pars{1/2}.
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^{2} \over x^{4} - 4x^{2} + 5}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> {x^{2}
>  \over
>  \pars{x - 5^{1/4}\expo{-\ic\phi/2}}
>  \bracks{x - \pars{\color{#ff0000}{-5^{1/4}\expo{-\ic\phi/2}}}}
>  \pars{x - \color{#ff0000}{5^{1/4}\expo{\ic\phi/2}}}
>  \bracks{x - \pars{-5^{1/4}\expo{\ic\phi/2}}}} 
> \,\dd x
> \end{align}
> The $\color{#ff0000}{\large\mbox{red}}$ terms are the poles in the upper complex half plane. So, can you take it from here ?.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But is there another way just using the "i" instead of using the exponential?